# Determine run time of a function using clock()

Tags: c, time, clock

I'm trying to determine the runtime of a function in C using `clock()`.
This is the code so far:

```
time_t start, end;
start = clock();
// Function here
end = clock();
printf("Time was: %lf\n", ((double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
```

And it returns `Time was: 0.030000`. If I add a delay of a few seconds it then displays `Time was: 0.500000`. How can I get it to display properly in milliseconds? eg. `Time was: 500 milliseconds` or `Time was: 30 milliseconds`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display time in milliseconds, multiply the time in seconds by `1000`:

```
printf("Time was: %d\n", (1000*(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
```

The above code truncates the time to the smallest millisecond.